# Troubleshooting why subsetting of spatial object does not work

Tags: r, subset, spatial

I am trying to subset a 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' in R, but the methods proposed in other threads seem not to work. I am using R version 3.3.2 and I am accessing it through R studio on a mac.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide my dataset, (because I cannot subset my data).

This,

```
sp2 <- sp1[sp1@data$compound_found == 1, ]
```

produced the following error:

> ```
> Error in sp1[sp1@data$compound_found == 1, ] :    cannot get a slot ("Polygons") from an object of type "NULL"
> ```

despite

```
sp1@data$compound_found == 1

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE 
[14] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
[27]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

sp2 <- sp1["compound_found" == 1, ]
```

does not create an error, but creates an empty object

```
nrow(sp2@data) # returns 0
```

Any explanation why I cannot subset the way I was trying? How could I do it instead?

EDIT:

```
class(sp1)
```

returns

> ```
> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
> attr(,"package")
> [1] "sp"
> ```

Comment: `...object of type "NULL"` is a clue. What is the output of `class(sp1)` ?

Comment: Thanks SymbolixAU, I provided the information now above.

Comment: `sp2  < - sp1[data$compound_found == 1, ]` works?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't think data is an object; it's a function. "Error in data$compound_found : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: Type `str(sp1)` and describe what slots of `sp1` are you trying to subset and return?

Comment: I want to subset sp1 by "compound_found" which is a factor with 2 levels ("0" and "1") under @data (data.frame). Is this the info you asked for?

Comment: Do you want only `sp1@data` subset or also `sp1@polygons`?

Comment: also sp1@polygons. I want to plot fields with "compound_found == 1" in a map.  sp1@polygons is a List of 37 class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to describe troubleshooting that arrived at solution with help from OP.

A `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` usually can be subsetted as the OP has done above in the original question:

```
sp1[sp1@data$compound_found == 1, ]
```

Not sure where the error comes from without seeing the data.  To troubleshoot, you can examine the structure of `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to see where the error might be coming from.

```
str(sp1)
```

You can also separately subset `@data` and `@polygons` to check if it's pulling the right elements.

If you want to subset `sp1@data` you can use:

```
sp1@data[1:ncol(sp1@data)][sp1@data$compound_found == 1,]
```

To get `sp1@polygons`:

```
sp1@polygons[sp1@data$compound_found == 1]
```

Note that `@data` and `@polygons` should be the same length.  See http://www.dpi.inpe.br/gilberto/tutorials/software/R-contrib/sp/html/SpatialPolygons.html

"data: the number of rows in data should equal the number of Polygons-class objects in Sr"

Check that `nrow(sp1@data)` and `length(sp1@polygons)` are the same.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, but I also want to subset the polygons to plot them.

Comment: Edited the answer to get at `sp1@polygons` also.

Comment: This returns `Error in sp1@polygons[sp1@data$compound_found == 1, ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: Sorry typo with extra comma, it's corrected: `sp1@polygons[sp1@data$compound_found == 1]`.  Usually it can be subsetted like this: `sp1[sp1@data$compound_found == 1, ]`, not sure where your error comes from without the data.

Comment: The first one returns a list rather than a spatial object and the second one is the one I tried before that produces the error. I think the problem is the different dimension of the polygons and data slots: `length(sp1@polygons) # 37`
`length(sp1@data) # 32`. Can this be causing the error?

Comment: I will check if I made an error merging the the spatial with the non-spatial data.

Comment: Yes that should be the issue. See under `data`: http://www.dpi.inpe.br/gilberto/tutorials/software/R-contrib/sp/html/SpatialPolygons.html. "the number of rows in data should equal the number of Polygons-class objects in Sr"

Comment: Thanks Djork! This was indeed the problem. I had a duplicate row in my data.frame (df) and merged it then the wrong way with a spatial object (sp). `sp@data <- merge(sp@data, df)` rather than `sp <- merge(sp, df)`. This caused the discrepancy between the dimensions of `@data` and `@polygons`. Can you summarise the troubleshoot advice you gave me in your answer? I will accept it then.